# Await is not working inside a method javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, async-await

I have an ajax call which return some data. Code is:

```
function ProductCodeLookUp() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: "/ProductInventory/GetProductCodeHirerchy",
            type: "get", //send it through get method
            async: false,
            data: {
                productCode: $('#ProductCodeText_Id').val()
            },
            success: function (response) {
                debugger;
                if (response != null && (response.tissueClassificationType != null || response.tissueClassificationType != null)) {
                    $('#productCodeTable_id').show();
                    $('#ProductCodeNotExistsWarning_id').hide();

                    //addOptionsToSelect(response, 'size_id', $('input[id=size_id]').val());
                    $('#ProductCodeTextClassification_Id').text(response.tissueClassificationType);
                    $('#ProductCodeTextTissueType_Id').text(response.tissueType);
                    $('#ProductCodeTextProduct_Id').text(response.tissueDefinition);
                    $('#ProductCodeTextSize_Id').text(response.tissueDefinitionSize);
                }
                else {
                    $('#ProductCodeNotExistsWarning_id').show();
                    $('#productCodeTable_id').hide();
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                //Do Something to handle error
            }
        });
    }
```

I Have to take some decision on the basis of the data returned by this Ajax call. The method where i am calling `ProductCodeLookUp()` method is:

```
async function checkRequiredFields() {
var isValid = false;
if (checkRequiredFieldsSubMethod() == true) {
            if (AddProductInBulk() == true) {
                if (QualityChecksValidation() == true) {
                    debugger;
                    var res = await ProductCodeLookUp();
                    if (res.tissueDefinitionSize != null)
                        isValid = true;
                    else
                        isValid = false;
                  }
                }
         }
        debugger;
        return isValid;
    }
```

Issue is that it does not await on the `ProductCodeLookUp()` method. I have to wait for the result of this method and on the basis of result make a decision that whether to return true or false. But i am unable to do this. What can be the possible issue.

Comment: Does `ProductCodeLookUp()` return a `Promise` for the `await` to handle?

Comment: Yes, it does return a promise. @TimothyAlexisVass

Comment: And it's the same domain?

Comment: Will you please tidy the JavaScript indentations?

Comment: Why `async: false` when you're going to wait for the "Promise" to resolve anyway?

Comment: `$.ajax` doesn't return a promise, rather, it returns returns the XMLHttpRequest object that it creates. You could try to return the promise by yourself and resolve it in the `success` handler.

Comment: @WiktorZychla `$.ajax()` returnes a `$.Deferred` object which is a `Promise`-like object that also works with `await` -> https://jsfiddle.net/fL5okpqm/

Answer (score -2):

Wrap the ajax call in a promise that resolves on success and rejects on error.

```js
function ProductCodeLookUp() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => $.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function (response) {
      // ...
      resolve();
    },
    error: function (response, status, err) {
       // ...
       reject(err);
    }
  }));
}
```

Also, set `async` to true

Comment: This is an anti-pattern. JQuery Ajax already returns a thenable.